# Why methods doesn't see values set in constructor? (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a class AuthorizationService like this:

```
@Service
public class AuthorizationService {

private final String code;
private final String client_id;
private final String redirect_uri;
private final String scope;
private final String show_dialog;

@Autowired
public AuthorizationService(
        @Value("${spotify-property.response_type}") String code,
        @Value("${spotify-property.client_id}") String client_id,
        @Value("${spotify-property.redirect_uri}") String redirect_uri,
        @Value("${spotify-property.scope}") String scope,
        @Value("${spotify-property.redirect_uri}") String show_dialog) {
    this.code = code;
    this.client_id = client_id;
    this.redirect_uri = redirect_uri;
    this.scope = scope;
    this.show_dialog = show_dialog;
    System.out.println(code); //works
}

public ResponseEntity<HttpHeaders> getSpotifyRedirectionCode() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    System.out.println(client_id); //doesn't work
    System.out.println(this.code); //does not work either
    System.out.println(redirect_uri);
    System.out.println(scope);
    System.out.println(show_dialog);

    //more code doesn't matter

    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
}
```

Why these variables are ok in constructor but in methods are null, how to set them in correct way? Also

```
@Value("${spotify-property.response_type}") 
private final String code;
```

does not work either.

Comment: Your constructor implementation should be working. How are you calling `getSpotifyRedirectionCode()`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, once you set the class fields in the constructor, if you print the class field do you get the expected result?  E.g `System.out.println(this.code); `

Answer (score 0):

Your class fields are final so get instantiated without your configuration values.
You can either use the constructor as you have before, or remove the final from your fields.

Comment: `final` fields can be set in constructors, which is what OP is doing.

Comment: @George my comment was more towards the reason the Op was not seeing any values in his fields when declaring them `final` with @Value annotations. I see your point though, when using his current implementation he should see the values printed in the `getSpotifyRedirectionCode()` method.

Comment: @MrFisherman I am glad it is working for you now. As setting the variables to static resolves it, this could point towards a root cause of a new instance of your class being initialised and subsequently replacing your previous instance?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if my answer is 100% correct. But I believe that you cannot change final variables. The right way would be to remove the final keyword and keep the @Value annotations on the fields and the you don't have to use it in the constructor.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthorizationService {

    @Value("${spotify-property.response_type}")    
    private String code;
    
    @Value("${spotify-property.client_id}") 
    private String client_id;
    
    @Value("${spotify-property.redirect_uri}") 
    private String redirect_uri;
    
    @Value("${spotify-property.scope}") 
    private String scope;
    
    @Value("${spotify-property.redirect_uri}")
    private String show_dialog;

public ResponseEntity<HttpHeaders> getSpotifyRedirectionCode() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    System.out.println(client_id); //works
    System.out.println(this.code); //works too
    System.out.println(this.redirect_uri);
    System.out.println(this.scope);
    System.out.println(this.show_dialog);
    //more code doesn't matter
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
} }
```

Comment: `final` fields can be set in constructors, which is what OP is doing.

Comment: You answer is wrong. Data from `.properties` file must be declared in method or constructor.

Comment: I've set these values as static and now its working.